# CDBCriteria->select fetching all fields instead of the mentioned field in the select in yii

Tags: yii

Mentioned `$criteria->select=>'id,Name'` as well as tried `$criteria->select=>array('id,Name')` but after exec using

```
        `$model = Person::model()->findAll( $criteria );            
         echo (CJSON::encode($model));
```

I could see its showing all the fields instead of only with id and name.

What am i missing?

Comment: are there any typos in the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $model that Yii returns contains an array of Person objects. Each of these Person object will only have filled their id and Name attributes, the rest will contain null values. This is the way CActiveRecord works :)